# Add values of only matching array elements PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say I've got an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filmType] =>  Symphony 15%
            [rollSize] => 36
            [linearFt] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [filmType] =>  Symphony 15%
            [rollSize] => 36
            [linearFt] => 3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [filmType] =>  Symphony 15%
            [rollSize] => 48
            [linearFt] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [filmType] =>  Symphony 25%
            [rollSize] => 36
            [linearFt] => 7
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [filmType] =>  Symphony 35%
            [rollSize] => 36
            [linearFt] => 10
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [filmType] =>  Symphony 35%
            [rollSize] => 36
            [linearFt] => 10
        )
```

How is it possible to add up the [linearFt] of ONLY unique array elements.  By unique I mean [filmtype] and [rollSize] the same.

I have tried multible ways including searching array, array filter, and usort...  I am new to PHP and this is NOT homework.  Thanks for any help!

So my output would be:

```
$totalsArray = Array(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [filmType] =>  Symphony 15%
            [rollSize] => 36
            [linearFt] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [filmType] =>  Symphony 15%
            [rollSize] => 48
            [linearFt] => 3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [filmType] =>  Symphony 25%
            [rollSize] => 48
            [linearFt] => 7
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [filmType] =>  Symphony 35%
            [rollSize] => 48
            [linearFt] => 20
        )
```

Comment: Also, make sure when you ask questions to mark correct answers when received. Your other questions need that attention. (Or people may stop helping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. I would attack this with a `foreach` loop to get each array, then accumulate the different types and sizes and add them as I go. It would look like this:

```
$filmTotals = array();
$filmTemp   = array();
foreach ($filmInventory as $film){
    $filmTemp[$film['filmType']][$film['rollSize']] = $filmTemp[$film['filmType']][$film['rollSize']] + $film['linearFt'];
}

// A second foreach to resort into the final format, nested to get the keys out to rename them correctly
foreach ($filmTemp as $filmType=>$film){
    foreach ($film as $filmSize=>$filmLength){
        $filmTotals[] = array('filmType'=>$filmType, 'rollSize'=>$filmSize, 'linearFt'=>$filmLength);
    } //END inner foreach
} // END outer foreach
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I see some glaring issues.

Comment: Derp! Yeah, sloppy copypasta, sorry. I've used a similiar structure before...only with everything correctly labeled. Fix'd.

Comment: Thank you Malovich! Works like a charm.  I will study and learn from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($myArray as $value) {
   $sumsArray[$value['filmType']_$value['rollSize']]['length_tally'][] = $value['linearFt'];
}
```

Will group all similar `filmType` and `rollSize` and then you can use [array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) with the `length_tally` array to give the total length.

The output won't be exactly what you're looking for, but should put you on the right path.